# How to separate SQL column data separated by comma to individual values and then count these values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Am using a SQL command in PHP to count the no of values inserted in a column named `attack_type`. I want to count the occurrence of individual values like `website defacement` in the whole column of the table. But here the column `attack_type` contain different values, separated by a comma and the count is treating whole column data as a string. Below is my current SQL statement with its output

I tried explode print_r in PHP

```
SELECT attack_type, 
       count(*) as number 
FROM data_input_test 
GROUP BY attack_type
```

Here is the output of the above statement 
generated:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TyRL_Mh0OOJWaCpFczxmBr34No9LUpzH

But what I want is :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eeA_1TCER0WMpZwSkBDMzRtRa8xihbZd

and so on. The above desired output is edited to show what I exactly want.

Other answer on stackoverflow and on other forums are either irrelevant or are using regrex or a new table creation in one or the other way. That I don't want as my hosting has some limitations. My hosting doesnt provide creation of triggers, regrex or creation of temp tables

Comment: Please include the actual and expected data here, linked content can disappear overtime. Also, a table definition would be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: @gaborsch the links above has the actual and expected outputs and am sory am unable to share the full table here but this column is varchar type

Comment: @gaborsch this is not a duplicate question.I searched everywhere but no answer anywhere and also i want count of these values and individually

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store duplicated values in a string.  Use a junction/association table instead.

Answer (score 1):

I may have a solution for this but don't know how to apply here. Possible here: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql

Please someone explain me how to apply the same here.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count comma-separated values in rows, you can use:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(attack_type) - LENGTH(replace(attack_type, ',', '')) +1) AS TotalCount
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: I don't want total count of the data in that column. What I want is count of individual values in the attack_type column for the whole table. Your query will output 32 as there are 32 values inserted in the column of this table. But I want like how many times some value occurred for eg website defacement occurred for 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally worked around to get my work done using the select only. This only works if you have a finite set of data or specifically less than 64 values.

1. Change your column datatype to 'set' type. And enter your set values.
2. Now use select, count, find_in_set and union functions of sql.
3. Example:

   ````
   union select 'Un-patched Vulnerable Software Exploitaion'as type, count(*) as number from data_input_test where find_in_set('Un-patched Vulnerable Software Exploitaion',attack_type)```
   ````

and so on for all your values

I know this is not how you should do but as the legends say this works